# -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, aem

I have an AEM project with Eclipse settings that I'm trying to build over in IntelliJ. When trying to run it, I'm getting the following error:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set
```

- I'm using Java jfk1.8.0_321, maven 3.8.4, and IntelliJ 2021.3.2
- I have JAVA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME, M2_HOME, and M2 all set as environment properties in my system.
- Settings > Build Tools > Maven > Runner (VM Options: -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME)

In my runtime config I have a maven config:

- run: clean install
- Profiles: adobe-public
- Maven Options: inherit from settings
- Java Options > VM Options: -jar [crx-quickstart.jar path] -debug [port] -forkargs -- -Xmx3072m

I'm not getting this error on Eclipse, so I'm not sure whats been set incorrectly here. Does anyone know what may be the mismatch?

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158549#focus=Comments-27-1517575.0-0

Comment: First why are you setting VM Options for running Maven? Apart from that setting `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME)` is simply wrong..second M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME and M2 are not needed. Just import via IntelliJ directly the project...The only environment variable which is needed is: `JAVA_HOME` or you can select the JDK(SDK) via IDEA...

Comment: @khmarbaise I set those things based on how-tos to address this error, because I was originally doing what you say and was still getting this error. Even the solution posted by Konstantin suggests setting that vm option for maven runner...